# Assignment 3 in Procedural Programming

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing procedural programming and for my final assignment I have to create an application that will allow the user to do the following:

- Allow the user to enter the customer’s details: name, postcode and loyalty card details
- Check if the card has expired
- Check the loyalty card number is valid by:

  - Allowing the user to enter the 8 digits shown on the front of the card
  - Removing the 8th digit and storing it as ‘check_digit’
  - Reversing the numbers
  - Multiplying the 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th digits by 2
  - If the result of the multiplication is greater than 9 then subtract 9 from the result
  - Adding together the resulting 7 digits
  - Checking if the sum of the added digits plus the ‘check_digit’ is divisible by 10
- Output whether the loyalty card is valid or not
- Output customer and loyalty card details.

But, how do I go about removing the 'last digit' then storing it as a check_digit?  Sorry if this is vague, this is copied directly from my assignment brief.

Comment: Do your homework at home, alone.

Comment: What's the point of reversing the numbers, digits `1, 3, 5, 7` includes the same numbers forward or backward and addition is commutative (i.e. `a + b = b + a`)

Answer (score 0):

To get the last digit, you have to divide the number by 10 and get the remainder.

For example, to get the last digit of 123, you can do 123 % 10 which results to 3.

To remove the last digit, you have to divide the number by 10 and discard the remainder.

For example, to remove the last digit of 123, you can do 123 // 10 which results to 12.

Comment: Why are we entering the card number as a number instead of text again?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's how many of the introductory programming courses handle it. Although, technically speaking, in practical application this would be wrong. But based on the level that I assumed from the question I doubt they have worked on string operations yet.

Comment: I will give this a shot.  I appreciate the help, thank you.  Sorry if this was in any way vague once again.